# passwordValidator option in passport local mongoose doesn't work

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport-local

I am trying to validate password, during registration process, with passport local mongoose but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error but when I register with a password that does not fit the validation criteria, it gets accepted. Here is the UserSchema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    displayname: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date,
    avatar: String,
    Bio: String,
    isAdmin: {type: Boolean, default: false}

});

var passwordValidator = function(password, cb){
        var regex = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/;
        if(!password.match(regex)){
            return cb(null, false)
        }
        return cb(null, true);
    }

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
    usernameField: "email",
    errorMessages: {
        IncorrectPasswordError: "Password incorrect",
        IncorrectUsernameError: "There is no account registered with that email",
        UserExistsError: "A user with the given email is already registered"
    },
    passwordValidator: passwordValidator
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Registration code:

```
router.post("/register", upload.single("avatar"), function(req, res){
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, function(err, result){
        if(err) {
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            return res.redirect("back");
        }
        var newUser = new User({displayname: req.body.displayname,
        firstName: req.body.firstName, 
        lastName: req.body.lastName, 
        email: req.body.email,
        Bio: req.body.bio,
        avatar : result.secure_url
       });

        if(req.body.adminCode === "secretcode123"){
          newUser.isAdmin = true;
       }



       User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
         if(err){
            console.log(err); 
            req.flash("error", err.message);
            return res.redirect("/register");
        }

        passport.authenticate("local")(req,res, function(){
            req.flash("success", "Welcome " + " " + user.displayname);
            res.redirect("/campground");
        })
    });
    })
```

How do I get it to validate the password?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define Passport local strategy for passport-local-mongoose, that's why you are getting like that.Hence your code doesn't have anything to compare your password with. So without any local strategy, authentication will be success full every time.

If you are using Passport-local-mongoose ,it will create a salt and hash itself by using the given password. Hence you don't have to store your password in mongoose. 
`User.register()`
 is a default passport-local-mongoose function for that.
So your user schema should look like

```
    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {  
    type: String,
    unique: true
},
name:String,
address: String});
```

See here i didn't mentioned password in user schema.

Then you should define your passport-local strategy. For Passport-local-mongoose it should be like

`passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));` 
where user is your exported usershema.

If you are not using passport-local-mongoose, then local strategy code will be different, not like the one given above.

Then you should do serialise and deserialize your passport. It is like this for passport-local-mongoose

```
 passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
 passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I think you already know to initialise passport like this

```
app.use(passport.initialize());     
app.use(passport.session())
```

now its time for authentication. Code is

```
  `passport.authenticate('local',function (err, user, info) { if(err){
   res.redirect("/register");
     } else{
      if (! user) {
       res.redirect("/register");
      } else{
        req.login(user, function(err){
          if(err){
             res.redirect("/register");
          }else{
        res.redirect("/campground");`
          }
        })
      }
     }
  })(req, res);`
```

If you want to display the error message from passport-local-mongoose you can console the info from passport.authenticate.

If you want to know more details go through https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

If you are using passport-local-mongoose, the module itself will create an salt and hash and it will compare the password itself while authentication. You dont have to write password validator for that.